# Comparison signed and unsigned char

Tags: c++, c, unsigned-char

It seems so strange. I found misunderstanding. I use gcc with char as signed char. I always thought that in comparison expressions(and other expressions) signed value converts to unsigned if necessary.

```
int a = -4;
unsigned int b = a;
std::cout << (b == a) << std::endl; // writes 1, Ok
```

but the problem is that

```
char a = -4;
unsigned char b = a;
std::cout << (b == a) << std::endl; // writes 0
```

what is the magic in comparison operator if it's not just bitwise?

Comment: First one outputs 1, are you sure? [Gcc disagrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeac0b4860185e10).

Comment: Neither the first nor the second one outputs `1`.

Comment: Yes, the first one outputs 1 and the second outputs 0. Both are results of default promotions.

Comment: @R.., again, [no, they don't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b47aa67c5522577).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the second `-` sign.

Comment: [Mandatory watching](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n).

Comment: `what is the magic in comparison operator if it's not just bitwise?` If it were just a bitwise comparison then there wouldn't be much point in having both signed and unsigned types.

Comment: You should note that unlike int which is equivelent to signed int, char is NOT signed char, it's a distinct type from signed char and unsigned char.

Comment: Didn't you mean `unsigned xxx b = a;` for both cases? It would explain the confusion.

Comment: You say you "use gcc with char as signed char". Just to be clear, `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are always three distinct types. `char` always has the same size, signedness, and representation as *either* `signed char` *or* `unsigned char`; the implementation defines which one it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard

> 6 If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands; each of the
>   operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and
>   false if it is false.

So in this expression

```
b == a
```

of the example

```
char a = -4;
unsigned char b = -a;
std::cout << (b == a) << std::endl; // writes 0
```

the both operands are converted to type `int`. As the result signed char propagets its signed bit and two values become unequal.

To demonstrate the effect try to run this simple example

```
{
    char a = -4;
    unsigned char b = -a;

    std::cout << std::hex << "a = " << ( int )a << "'\tb = " << ( int )b << std::endl;

    if ( b > a ) std::cout << "b is greater than a, that is b is positive and a is negative\n";
}
```

The output is

```
a = fffffffc'   'b = 4
b is greater than a, that is b is positive and a is negative
```

Edit: Only now I have seen that definitions of the variables have to look as

```
    char a = -4;
    unsigned char b = a;
```

that is the minus in the definition of b ahould not be present.

Comment: No, no (well, not in the first example at least).

Comment: The quote is incomplete. If you compare an unsigned and a signed type of the same rank and "less" than `int`, the signed operand is converted to unsigned type.

Comment: @jrok, can you cite the standard on that?

Comment: @ jrok It seems it was not clear from my post what code snippet I was considering. I uodated my post that it would be more clear.

Comment: @Jefffrey To be honest, I don't feel like it, sorry :) But the quote applies when you compare unsigned char and signed char. In that case, yes, they are promoted to int.

Comment: @Jefffrey: Read `[C++11: 5/9]`

Comment: @ jrok In the quote there is written clear that it is applied to arithmetic types.

Comment: @Vlad: Nobody has disputed that.

Comment: Thank you, I made mistake when wrote unsigned char b = -a; But implicit conversion to int is the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Bikineev It is funny that except me nobody saw this typo.:)

Comment: `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are almost always promoted to (signed) `int` by the "usual arithmetic conversions". But if `CHAR_MAX > INT_MAX` or `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, then `char` or respectively `unsigned char` will instead be promoted to `unsigned int`. This can happen only if `CHAR_BIT >= 16` and `sizeof (int) == 1` -- and, for plain `char`, if `char` happens to be an unsigned type. You'll never encounter this on a system with 8-bit bytes.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson, It is very unusual case that sizeof( int ) == sizeof( short ) == sizeof( char ) == 1. I am not even sure that the C++ Standard allows this and that CHAR_MAX can be gretaer than INT_MAX. At keast this contradicts the notion of rank.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I'm certain it's allowed in C; I'm nearly certain it's allowed in C++. Consider `CHAR_BIT == 16`, plain `char` is unsigned, `CHAR_MAX == 65536`, `sizeof (int) == 1`, `INT_MAX == 32767`. I'd be interested in seeing a clause in the standard that this would violate. (Similarly, `UINT_MAX > LONG_MAX` isn't even particularly unusual; `char` is unusual in that it can be either signed or unsigned.) BTW, if you want to notify me in a comment, you can't have a space between the at-sign and my name.

Comment: @Keith Thompson  I am not sure neither relative to C nor to C++. This contradicts to the paragraph of the C++ Standard (and there is the same paragraph in the C Standard) "The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with a smaller size." So the usual arithmetic conversion has no any sense. At keast there is no need to convert to int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Can you be more explicit about the contradiction you see? I don't see it. Note that in the case I'm talking about, `char` is an *unsigned* type, so the sentence you quoted doesn't apply.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson Now char has a rank higher than int. So there is no any sense in the integer promotion.

Answer (score 3):

Since an `(unsigned) int` is at least 16 bits wide, let's use that for instructional purposes:

In the first case: `a = 0xfffc`, and `b = (unsigned int) (a) = 0xfffc`

Following the [arithmetic conversion rules](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT02-CPP.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules), the comparison is evaluated as:

`((unsigned int) b == (unsigned int) a)` or `(0xfffc == 0xfffc)`, which is `(1)`

---

In the 2nd case: `a = 0xfc`, and `b = (unsigned char) ((int) a)` or:

`b = (unsigned char) (0xfffc) = 0xfc` i.e., *sign-extended to `(int)` and truncated*

Since and `int` can represent the range of both the `signed char` and `unsigned char` types, the comparison is evaluated as: *(zero-extended vs. sign-extended)*

`((int) b == (int) a)` or `(0x00fc == 0xfffc)`, which is `(0)`.

---

Note: The [C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) and [C++](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/INT02-CPP.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) integer conversion rules behave the same way in these cases. Of course, I'm assuming that the `char` types are 8 bit, which is typical, but only the minimum required.

Comment: There was a typo in the original post. So in your first example a and b should have the same internal representation 0xfffc